# State map is blank in Power BI Desktop

Tags: reporting-services, data-visualization, powerbi

I have state ID and value column in my dataset.
Can I create simple filled map of the USA?

In Power BI I put `State` in the `Location` and Premium under `Color Saturation`. (There is no `Value` column)

[image]

But still unable to display map.

[image]

Comment: Which type of map are you using?

Comment: I am using Filled map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in report view, click on `StateID`, then click on `Modeling tab` =>in properties group make sure your `DataCategory` is set to `State or Province`.

Comment: Maybe you could try different DataCategory types...From what I see, issue should be coming from there..

Answer (score 0):

I updated the last version and after that it started to display map correctly.